# Jboss 7.1.1 correct hibernate dependencies

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jboss, jboss-modules

I'm reviewing pom.xml of an old project which I'm trying to run on Jboss AS 7.1.1. This pom contains a lot of dependencies with artifacts like:

- hibernate-core
- hibernate-validator
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api
- hibernate-entitymanager
- ...

As Jboss 7.1.1 has a module `org.hibernate` I've managed to remove these dependencies except of `hibernate-core` by creating `\META-INF\jboss-deployment-structure.xml` with following content:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.hibernate"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

So in order to be able to compile WAR file I need to have this dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

but I can't understand why I can't set it with `provided` scope. If it is included in `org.hibernate` module, why I can't do so? If I set it as `provided`, I'm getting the following error:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
```

I want to set it with `provided` scope just to exclude it from WAR file

Answer (score 1):

Instead of jboss-deployment-structure.xml if you are using maven in project better to provide hibernate and supported module as manifest entry. you can achieve this by following code in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<archive>
<manifestEntries>
<Dependencies>
org.infinispan,org.hibernate
</Dependencies>
</manifestEntries>
</archive>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

then add your other required dependencies with the scope provided so they can be loaded at run time with out bundling in war, use following as an example.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>

    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Also make sure the corresponding database dialect jar exist in the module and have entry in module.xml...

Comment: Looks like I will be not able to make it work, as I'm experiencing the same problem as [these](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/195925) guys and performing changes in jboss modules is not possible in my case, as I will not be able to do it in other environments. But thanks for help.